# To whom does the Iranian leader refer as an Israeli official?

Tags: united-states, israel, iran

In 2002, Iran's political and religious leader, [Mr. Ali Khamenei, delivered a speech that says](https://english.khamenei.ir/news/137/Leader-s-Address-to-Youngsters-in-Sistan-Baluchestan-Province):

> One of the top officials of the Zionist usurper regime of Israel made
> a recommendation to the Americans last year, which was fully reflected
> in foreign media and the internet. This is not a secret or hidden
> matter. His recommendation to the Americans was not to waste their
> time with Iraq, North Korea, and countries like these. Your main issue
> is Iran if you want to deal with the Middle East, don't waste your
> time on Iraq. Go to Iran; that's where the center and source are. But
> Iran is not like Iraq, North Korea, or Afghanistan that can be
> conquered by military attack. The Islamic system and government rely
> on the people; the people have preserved it. You must make the people
> abandon it. The way to do this is to push the people towards Western
> culture and literature, and American culture and education, causing
> them to deviate from their religion, culture, tradition, and history.
> When people abandon these affiliations, after a few years, without
> spending any capital, with a sudden military attack and movement, you
> can remove this great obstacle, namely the Islamic system!
>
> Earlier last year, when villages and cities in Afghanistan were being
> destroyed by American missiles and the oppressed people of Afghanistan
> were being attacked by American bombings, a US military strategist
> said, "If instead of these missiles, you send women's underwear, and
> Western and American-style skimpy clothing and sensual items to Afghan
> youth, you can occupy Afghanistan without spending on these weapons.
> The money for weapons will remain in your pocket. Instead of bombs and
> missiles, promote pornographic CDs, enticing landscapes, and sensual
> literature among them; then your job will become easier."

**Who is the person that has stated this message to American leaders, and what has been America's response to this message?**

Comment: @Anonymous Somehow. [Here is the English page](https://english.khamenei.ir/news/137/Leader-s-Address-to-Youngsters-in-Sistan-Baluchestan-Province) of that speech

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its an old quote and likely partisan interpretation of a translation and it would be impossible to locate and confirm the source or sources.

Comment: @JamesK and it could be censored by Google and the media! Right? Faire enough, isn't it? Do you have the same opinion about US presidents when they say Iran is building nukes? Or Palestine belongs to its occupiers? And of course Iran is still invisible, if it wasn't, they would have attacked it like other countries.

Comment: What makes you think this person needs to have actually existed?  Sounds very much like a Trumpian "people have told me" and no one really bothers looking for their sources anymore.

Comment: @Anonymous I found the answer, but the post is closed! Vote for reopening

Comment: @C.F.G Thank you, I read your comment and the article you mentioned, have you found a clue of the other article you talked about?

Comment: @Anonymous Unfortunately no. If you find it, share it please.